# Does Openshift allow self-signed certificates?

Tags: certificate, openshift, cloudflare, self-signed

Say you implement an application on Openshift and put it behind Cloudflare.

Since Cloudflare offers universal certificates and allows self-signed certificate, can I use self-signed certificate on OpenShift for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a self signed certificate, it just won't show up as trusted by most browsers.

Comment: Well, since the browsers will see the Cloudflare certificate (which is ok), that won't be an issue.